# What does the C++ language standard say about how static_cast handles reducing the size of an integer?

Tags: c++, casting

I would like to know the rules specified by the C++ language standard for situations like:

```
long x = 200;
short y = static_cast<short>(x);
```

Is `y` guaranteed to be 200, or does the standard leave this up to the implementation to decide?  How well do various compilers adhere to the standard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case the `static_cast<>` is an 'explicit type conversion.  the standard has this to say about integral conversions in 4.7/3 "Integral conversions":

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

Since `short` is guaranteed to be able to hold the value `200` (`short` must be at least 16 bits), then for your specific example the answer is yes.

Various compilers adhere to this behavior quite well - it's been that way since the pre-ANSI days of C, and so much code depends on the behavior that compiler vendors seem reluctant to even issue warnings about the possibility of truncation.

Answer (score -2):

If the value falls within the range of a `short` then the value is guaranteed to be correct, which in your case is true, so `y == 200`.

If it falls outside (e.g. `static_cast<short>(1000000000)`) then the behaviour is undefined. Most compilers will just truncate the binary digits down to the correct size.

Comment: Not undefined behavior, unspecified.

Comment: @GMan: not unspecified, but implementation-defined. There's a subtle difference - for implementation defined there's a specific behavior that the implementation needs to document, which is not necessary for unspecified behavior. The difference between 'unspecified' and 'undefined' behavior is that the there are generally a set of allowable behaviors for unspecified, while for undefined anything goes (including crashing).

Comment: @Michael:There's some room for argument over the limits on implementation defined behavior. In the C standard, the #pragma directive is defined as: "...causes the implementation to behave in an implementation-defined manner. The behavior might cause translation to fail or cause the translator or the resulting program to behave in a non-conforming manner." Two things are unclear: does this apply to "implementation-defined" in general, or just *this* I-D behavior? Does the same apply to C++, which doesn't include that wording, but doesn't say otherwise?

Comment: @Jerry: the wording for that case is specific to that case. For instance, whether `char` is signed is also I.D., but using a plain `char` may not cause the implementation to fail (obviously). `#pragma` is unusually free in what it can do, by design. This includes causing translations to fail. `#pragma WarningsAsErrors` could do that, and that's not something the standard want to outlaw.

Comment: @MSalters:I'm not sure it's so clear cut. I can't find a reference at the moment, but I'm quite certain I recall mention of this having been discussed by the committee, and there having been a fair number of committee members who did *not* consider it restricted to pragmas.

Comment: @Jerry: it IS clearcut that there is no _general_ rule, as I;'ve given an example of an unrestricted case (`#pragma`) and of a restricted case (`char` sign, 2 options). That clarifies that the behavior can differ. I haven't enumerated and classified all cases of ID behavior, as these two examples are sufficient to show there's more than one rule.